# Find matrix $A=M_{2 \times2}(\mathbb{C})$ that the solutions for $Ax=0$ are $\{ t\cdot \begin{pmatrix}i\\ 1+i\end{pmatrix} |t \in \mathbb{C}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> How to Find matrix $A=M_{2 \times2}(\mathbb{C})$ that the solutions for $Ax=0$  are $\{ t\cdot \begin{pmatrix}i\\ 1+i\end{pmatrix} |t \in \mathbb{C}\}$

my suggest answer :

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}ax_1+bx_2\\ cx_1+dx_2\end{pmatrix}$$

if i choose $t=1 \in \mathbb{C}$  so i get $$a\cdot i+b \cdot(1+i)=0 $$

$$c\cdot i+d \cdot(1+i)=0$$

so the only answer is $a=b=c=d=0$

thanks

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1+ i & -i\\ 1+i & - i\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

What about:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1+ i & -i\\ 1+i & -i\end{pmatrix}?$$

Don't forget that $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers.

Comment: are you sure of this A? it seems not singular

Comment: Yes it is not singular... and I made a typo. I was meaning your own $A$.